# save and view snapshot image from android device

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with saving image into an android device this is what i did 
My java class :

```
package com.test.app;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity
{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle myBundle) {
        super.onCreate(myBundle);

    }
public string GetPath(){
  return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
}
}
```

in eclipse i made my project as a jar file from `project setting --> set as library` , got the `jar file` from `libs` and copy past it in : `Plugins/Android` in my unity project directory , then created a new Manifest.xml as followed :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.test.app">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

then the unity c# class as followed :

```
public class ScreenShot : MonoBehaviour {
  AndroidJavaClass pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass;
  Public GameObject panl;
void Start()
{
    AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
        pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.test.app.MainActivity");
}
void OnMouseDown()
{
  StartCoroutine(takeShot());
}

private IEnumerator takeShot()
 {
   panl.SetActive(false); // the panl contain the button having this script `ScreenShot class` 
   Application.CaptureScreenshot("my_img.png");
   // on mobile it's at persistant data path
   string dir = Application.persistentDataPath + "/my_img.png";
   float timeOut = 0f;
   // check if file exists
   while (!File.Exists(dir))
  {
    Debug.Log("Cant find screenshot!");
    timeOut += Time.deltaTime;
    // it it takes too much give up
    if (timeOut > 5f) yield break; 
    yield return null;           
  }
  // If your path is correct
   string yourPath = pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass.CallStatic<string>("GetPath");
   Debug.Log(yourPath);
  File.Copy(dir, yourPath + "/my_img.png",true);
  // maybe delete source file here?
 }





}
```

but nothing is happening , i am not able to see my screenshot on the device 
can someone tell me what i did wrong ???

Comment: Any log errors? And `Application.CaptureScreenshot` saves the image to `Application.persistentDataPath`, you just have to copy it to your sdcard where you want

Comment: no errors , how can i copy it ??

Answer (score 0):

After taking screenshot you need to copy it, a coroutine like this should work well under this case,

```
private IEnumerator takeShot()
{
    Application.CaptureScreenshot("my_img.png");
    // on mobile it's at persistant data path
    string dir = Application.persistentDataPath + "/my_img.png";
    float timeOut = 0f;
    // check if file exists
    while (!File.Exists(dir))
    {
        Debug.Log("Cant find screenshot!");
        timeOut += Time.deltaTime;
        // it it takes too much give up
        if (timeOut > 5f) yield break; 
        yield return null;           
    }
    // If your path is correct
    string yourPath = pluginTutorialActivityJavaClass.CallStatic<string>("GetPath");
    Debug.Log(yourPath);
    File.Copy(dir, yourPath + "/my_img.png",true);
    // maybe delete source file here?
}
```

This is the basic idea, I assume your java code for getting external storage path works.Also don't forget to import `System.IO`.

Comment: i did what u said but my image is never copied 
i am able to see the image in the Application.persistentDataPath but the image is not being copied :/

Comment: after some work i realize that i should call it like this : `StartCoroutine(takeShot())` this work but if i want to hide the UI.panel containing the button before `Application.CaptureScreenshot("my_img.png");` the copy don't work and the image remain in the `dir` folder and the console give me `Cant find screenshot!`,i'll edit my answer to make it clear

Comment: If you see the image inside `dir` folder it should find the image I can't see any problem. maybe you should check your java code

Comment: i really don't know what is happening hahaha , does having the button inside the panel make a problem for `captureScreenshot` ?

Comment: but when i press on the button to save the image,the button is getting displayed on the screenshot,how to disable the button in the screen shot